# Can't seek through html video

Tags: google-chrome, video, http-headers

I'm using CakePHP for a kiosk app (using node-webkit/chromium), and I serve many videos at once, in a single page there can be up to 15 videos

Here is my controller code

```
public function _getVideoFullPath($id)
{
    $video = $this->Article->findById($id, array('Article.video_dir', 'Article.video'));
    $video_name = $video['Article']['video'];

    $file = $this->_getVideoDir($id).$video_name;

    return $file;
}

public function getVideo($id)
{
    $this->response->header(
        array(
            'Content-Type: video/webm',
            'Content-Length: ' . filesize($this->_getVideoFullPath($id))
        )
    );

    $this->response->cache('-1 minute', '+5 days');
    $this->response->file($this->_getVideoDir($id).'video'.$id.'-webm.webm', array('download' => true));
    return $this->response;
}
```

And the view

```
<video preload="auto" controls src="/article/articles/getVideo/<?php echo h($article['Article']['id']); ?>">
</video>
```

When I seek through the video, it no longer plays

The http headers:

[image: http requests]

[image: video http header]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:

The problem was `preload="auto"`, since chrome doesn't allow more than 6 simultaneous connections (and I have more than 15 videos preloading in one page)

A temporary solution to my problem was change preload to none.

Comment: Is this really related to CakePHP?  Have you tried creating a simple HTML or PHP page with the content?  My assumption is it's related to the content, not the framework, but - just a thought.

Comment: @Dave the problem was that chrome doesn't allow more than 6 concurrent connections is a single instance, so if there are more than 6 videos preloading, of course it will hang until one finish, and then load another (if I play another video, it will generate another request, plus the other ones loading in background)

I was thinking about cakephp because the file api changed from mediaviews to file response, but it's clear now

Comment: Probably worth editing the title of the question then to be more pertinent - likely to get more help.